# What is the motivation for these different definitions of smooth curve?

Tags: definition, smooth-manifolds, curves, smooth-functions

Let me ask a question. I see two different definitions of smooth curve. One is that smooth curve is $C^1$ (tangent continuous); The other is $C^{\infty}$  (infinitely differentiable). What is the motivation for this different definition?

Comment: Are you asking why people would study or use $C^1$ curves (or manifolds, or etc.) versus $C^\infty$ ones?

Comment: @anomaly Yes, both of them are called smooth curves. In manifold we say "smooth" generally refers to $C^{infty}$,while in other occasions we may only require $C^1$. Is it because manifold needs such strong restrictions and other places only need weak conditions? Why are these two conditions so different that they should be named "smooth"?

Comment: If you're, say, looking at integration along a curve, then $C^1$ is probably enough; that gives you a nice parametrization and so on. If you're studying smooth manifolds, then you probably want to consider $C^\infty$ curves to stay in the $C^\infty$ category. There's a theorem due to Whitney, though, that any $C^1$ manifold has a unique (up to $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism) $C^\infty$ structure on it, so there really isn't much of a difference.

Comment: @anomaly Thank you.

Comment: @anomaly 
One more question, is the Whitney theorem you mentioned called Whitney theorem or some other name?

Comment: What's usually called the (strong) Whitney theorem is the result that any smooth manifold $X^n$ can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. I don't think the result I mentioned has a specific name; it's almost a folklore theorem, though I think there's a proof in Hirsch and a few other standard references.

Comment: No thanks are necessary, but you're welcome.